# Django - Text isn't moving down

Tags: python, css, django

I made a class and named it ">My Hero Academy<".

I am trying to make it move down, but it is not moving down.

What is the problem? [Image](https://gyazo.com/e4b0e203f016f3b4f726a4eaa8e509a6)

I am trying to move it lower than my title, then a little left, but it is not moving at all.

```
<body>
    <div class="sidenav2">

        <h5>One Piece</h5>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

My full home page code

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %} 

{% block title%}
home
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .sidenav2 a {
            padding:6px 8px 6px 216px;
            left:100px;
            top:100px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:35px;
            color: #818181;
            display:block;
        
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sidenav2">

        <h5>My Hero Academy</h5>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css, Change this

```
 .sidenav2 a {
```

to

```
.sidenav2 h5 {
```